# Can't change the language on my desktop because i can't read it

Tags: windows-7

my desktop changed to some language and I have tried everything to change back to English. I want to restore to factory setting and since i can't read anything on screen i am totally lost. window 7 dell xps 6300

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/87317-display-language-change.html - see if this will show you how to get to the right spot to change the language

Comment: "I have tried everything", well then, I guess we can offer you nothing, since there's nothing left to try...  OR you could tell us exactly what "everything" you have tried already, so we can offer you some actual suggestions that you may not have tried already...

Answer (score 1):

Press **Win + R** Button then, type in **intl.cpl** hit Return Button (Enter). A menu will popup go to the 3rd Tab. Click the Second Button and Change your Language

Answer (score 1):

Boot in Safe Mode (keep F8 pressed as soon as Windows starts loading).   Safe mode is always in the base language the system used during install.

From there set the default system language back to whatever you want. Reboot and start normal again.

Comment: Because my solution was very mainstream lol.